# How do I parse a string into a record in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

In C, reading the data in a string and putting its data into a struct is fairly straight forward, you just use something along the lines of `sscanf` to parse your data:

```
struct ingredient_dose ingr;

char *current_amount = "5 tsp sugar";

sscanf(current_amount, "%d %s %s", &ingr.amount, ingr.unit, ingr.ingredient);
```

Which would fill the struct/record with the given data.

How would I do something similar in Haskell? I realise you can't mutate anything once it's made, so the procedure will obviously be a bit different from the C example, but I can't seem to find a decent guide that doesn't include parsing JSON.

Comment: Derive the Read class. If the string is given in Haskell syntax (eg. Ingr 5 "tsp" "sugar"), you can have GHC do it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haskell doesn't have any built-in function which does *exactly* what `scanf` does.

However, if your stuff is space-delimited, you could easily use `words` to split the string into chunks, and the `read` function to convert each substring into an `Int` or whatever.

```
parse :: String -> (Int, String, String)
parse txt =
  let [txt1, txt2, txt2] = words txt
  in  (read txt1, txt2, txt3)
```

What Haskell *does* have an abundance of is "real" parser construction libraries, for parsing complex stuff like... well... JSON. (Or indeed any other computer language.) So if your input is more complicated than this, learning a parser library is typically the way to go.

---

**Edit:** If you have something like

```
data IngredientDose = IngredientDose {amount :: Double, unit, ingredient :: String}
```

then you can do

```
parse :: String -> IngredientDose
parse txt =
  let [txt1, txt2, txt2] = words txt
  in  IngredientDose {amount = read txt1, unit = txt2, ingredient = txt3}
```

Comment: Added record example.